Could not find com.github.nabinbhandari:Android-Permissions:3.8
i’m encountering an issue while trying to build my Android project using Gradle. The build fails with the following error:

Could not find com.nabinbhandari.android:permissions:3.8.
Searched in the following locations:
- https://storage.googleapis.com/download.flutter.io/com/nabinbhandari/android/permissions/3.8/permissions-3.8.pom
- https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/nabinbhandari/android/permissions/3.8/permissions-3.8.pom
- https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/nabinbhandari/android/permissions/3.8/permissions-3.8.pom
- https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/nabinbhandari/android/permissions/3.8/permissions-3.8.pom
Required by:
project :app > project :flutter_storage_path

Images
What I tried:
Cleaned the Gradle project using ./gradlew clean in the terminal.
Rebuilt the project using ./gradlew build in the terminal.
What I expected:
I expected that cleaning and rebuilding the Gradle project would resolve any dependency issues and allow the project to build successfully without errors.
What actually resulted:
The build still failed with errors indicating that Gradle could not find the dependencies com.github.nabinbhandari:Android-Permissions:3.7 and com.nabinbhandari.android:permissions:3.8 in the specified repositories.
https://github.com/nabinbhandari/Android-Permissions

If it's a Flutter project, follow the instructions of building apk/aab from the Flutter documentation. Hopefully, that will help you better.

Even I faced a problem with com 'com.nabinbhandari.android:permissions:3.8'. Looks like the owner of the dependency might have removed it. After a lot of searching, I found out a fork dependency and it worked for me. You can check it out here:
https://github.com/nabinbhandari/Android-Permissions/issues/28#issuecomment-846410920
I used this in my java project, and hopefully it works for you in flutter. Cheers.

A forked version dependency from jitpack is working:
maven {
            url 'https://jitpack.io'
      }

thus replace the dependency:
   implementation 'com.nabinbhandari.android:permissions:3.8'

with
implementation 'com.github.Redman1037:Android-Permissions:3.8'

Visit the fork page.
